# Java RMI server registry connection observer trigger

Tags: java, rmi

Is it possible to get some kind of notification from the registry when a new server is connected to a local RMI registry instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not with the [standard registry interface](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/rmi/registry/Registry.html); there's nothing in it to allow you to register a callback with the registry for it to notify you by.

That's not to say that you couldn't write a registry that did this, extending the `Registry` interface with the necessary capabilities, etc. It's just that the standard registry *doesn't* do that. It's a very simple, primarily passive service (which has the advantage of there not being that much to go wrong with it, a good feature in a foundational component).

Answer (score 0):

No it is not. The question doesn't actually make sense. Connecting to a remote object happens when you call a remote method. It has nothing to do with the RMI Registry at all.

Comment: sure, the RMI provider needs to register with the registry in order for the registry to know that it is there. i want to capture/reacton that event.

Comment: @Pass That's a different question. That's not the client connecting to the local RMI instance, that's the server connecting to the Registry. I suggezt you clarify your requirement.